# Polygon (vector) is getting shifted w.r.t scale level of Raster

Tags: qgis, raster, scale

We have some 100+ georeferenced raster's in ecw format. All the rasters are in EPSG:20935 (Arc 1950/UTM 35S) reference system. We have captured the data_footprint of those rasters in the same CRS. But, if the scale level is say 60,000 or 40,000 QGIS is showing a shift between the data_footprint polygon and the respective raster. Once i change the scale to 20,000 or 10,000 the polygon and the raster boundary matches perfectly. Could anyone explain why this happens ?

[image]

Comment: Have you set vertex points exactly at the cormers?

Comment: Yes. Took vertex points exactly at all the four corners of the grid

Comment: Does the issue persist if you save the raster as geotiff, and alternatively both shape and raster in WGS84 UTM 35S?

Comment: Tried that. But still there is a shift in images wherever a tif & ecw's are adjacent to one another. https://geonet.esri.com/thread/111188 In this case, since all the files are ecw's i guess the shift is uniform.